# CXF: getting SOAP request and response XML on the client-side

Tags: java, cxf

I'd like to have a CXF client which allows me to see the SOAP XML request made and response received.

Use case: I'm writing a test GUI for the service for people who don't have access to my CXF service's logs to get an idea what the SOAP requests need to look like and what gets returned. (Since the interface is rather complicated, a generic / dynamic GUI like SOAP UI isn't helpful).

I've already read about CXF interceptors and know how I could hook them to my client (one for the "receive" and one for the "send" phase). But I can't think of a way of making the interceptor pass the request/response XML somehow back to the client's request.

Any suggestions / ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the code of org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Logging{In|Out}Interceptor.